How to cargo build for AWS ARM machines?
I get errors like this:
 = note: clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-pie' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
          ld: unknown options: --as-needed -Bstatic -Bdynamic --eh-frame-hdr -z --gc-sections -z -z 
          clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)


Couldn't easily find anything on the internet that solved this, so here is the solution that works for me consistently. I use Amazon's custom 2023 Linux AMI. Works flawlessly.
CARGO_TARGET_AARCH64_UNKNOWN_LINUX_GNU_LINKER=aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc RUSTFLAGS="-C target-cpu=native" cargo build --release --target "aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu"

Here is the command line by line:
CARGO_TARGET_AARCH64_UNKNOWN_LINUX_GNU_LINKER=aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc
RUSTFLAGS="-C target-cpu=native"
cargo build --release --target "aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu"

You can either export those variables, or include them as a prefix in all of your cargo commands.
Additionally, if you are running a t4g.nano (for example), you should use target-cpu=neoverse-n1 so that your release builds don't fail.
To determine the correct target cpu, you can use rustc --print target-cpus, or lscpu on the target system.

You can also persist the environment variables in .cargo/config.toml in the [env] table. And RUSTFLAGS even has a dedicated key in the [build] section.
